# To Obtain EPOCH Time Value from a Packed BIT Structure in C

Tags: c

I need to find out the Epoch time from a binary data file which has following data structure (it is a 12 byte structure):

```
Field-1 : Byte 1, Byte 2, + 6 Bits from Byte 3
Time-1  :                   2 Bits from Byte 3 + Byte 4
Time-2  : Byte 5, Byte 6, Byte 7, Byte 8
Field-2 : Byte 9, Byte 10, Byte 11, Byte 12
```

For Field-1 and Field-2 I do not have issue as they can be taken out easily.

I need time value in Epoch Time (long) as it has been packed in Bytes 5,6,7,8 and 3 and 4 as follows:

- Bytes 5 to 8 (32 bit word) Packs time value bits from 0 thru 31 (byte 5 has 0 to 7 bits,
   byte 6 has 8 to 15, byte 7 has 16 to 23, byte 8 has 24 to 31).

The remaining 10 bits of time value are packed in Bytes 3 and byte 4 as follows:

- byte 3 has 2 bits:32 and 33, and Byte 4 has remaining bits : 34 to 41.

So total bits for time value is 42 bits, packed as above.

I need to compute epoch value coming out of these 42 bits. How do I do it?

I have done something like this but not sure it gives me correct value:

```
typedef struct P_HEADER {
    unsigned int tmuNumber : 22; //sorry for the typo.
    unsigned int time1 : 10; // Bits 6,7 from Byte-3 + 8 bits from Byte-4
    unsigned int time2 : 32; // 32 bits: Bytes 5,6,7,8
    unsigned int traceKey : 32; 
} __attribute__((__packed__)) P_HEADER;
```

Then in the code:

```
P_HEADER *header1;

//get input string in hexa,etc..etc..
//parse the input with the header as :
header1 = (P_HEADER *)inputBuf;
// then print the header1->time1, header1->time2 ....
long ttime = header1->time1|header1->time2;
```

Is this the way to get values out?

Comment: Why 21 and not 22 bits?  What does packed do when you've got 31 bits in the first two bit fields?  Are the remaining two 32-bit fields oddly aligned?

Comment: Is your local `time_t` a 32-bit or 64-bit quantity?  What does your 42-bit time value contain when the represented time is 1970-01-01 00:00:00+00:00?  What value does it contain for 2012-03-29 07:33:55-08:00?  For Unix systems, the answers are 0 and 1333031635 respectively.

Comment: First, I think the tmuNumber is 22 bits (8+8+6), second, the  ttime you want will be time1 followed by ttime2 bits, isn't it? Then I think you need to do the following: `uint64_t ttime = (((uint64_t)header1->time1) << 32) + ((uint64_t)header1->time2);`

Comment: i think that's a miscount, he clearly describes that the first bit of padding is 22 bits long.  However, if I understand the specs correctly, time1 needs a shift first before `|'ing

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the value as you descibe it:

```
typedef struct P_HEADER {
    unsigned int tmuNumber : 22;
    unsigned int time1 : 10; // Bits 6,7 from Byte-3 + 8 bits from Byte-4
    unsigned int time2 : 32; // 32 bits: Bytes 5,6,7,8
    unsigned int traceKey : 32; 
} __attribute__((__packed__)) P_HEADER;

long ttime = ((uint64_t)header1->time1) << 32 | header1->time2;
```

Works only like that on little-endian machines though.